# Pass data from php mysql to pop up on same page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a link in a php while loop

```
echo "<a href = '#$product_id' onclick = 'pop_up()' id = 'linker'>See more</a>";
```

The pop up requires the product id to search the database but hash tag is client side. I tried to use javascript window.location.hash but the outcome was not very reliable.

Does anyone know a method preferably server side I could use to retain the active product id while I call the pop up, attain the product id, use it to query the database and output it in the pop up.

I have a session already started and tied to a different condition.
I tried to call the product id directly from the pop up but because of the loop I only get either the first or last in the array.

```
<?
while ($i < $num) {
$product_id=mysql_result($result,$i,"prod_id");
$title=mysql_result($result,$i,"lTitle");
//main page
echo "<b>" , $title;
echo "<a href = '#$product_id' onclick = 'pop_up()' id = 'linker'>See more</a>";
?>

<!------pop up--------->
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop_up(){
   document.getElementById('pop').style.display='block';
}
</script>

<div id="pop">
<p style='color:#6F0A0A; font-size:15px;'><? echo $product_id; ?></p>
</div>

<?
 $i++;
}   
?>
```

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: You probably could make use of [`sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: I have a session already starting and stopping under different conditions around that code.

Comment: FYI, the `mysql` extension is [deprecated](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php); you should use `mysqli` now.

Comment: @EmmyS it's better to use PDO.

Comment: @Ricbermo - I'm not debating which is better or worse; the fact is the most direct replacement for `mysql` is `mysqli`.

Comment: Thanks guy I'm looking into PDO now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try answering but to be honest the question is very vague and the code is a bit messy.

First off, you can simply send the product_id as a GET variable to the new popup and read it in PHP. Something like this will work:

```
    echo "<a href = 'http://www.mydomain.com/popup.php?product_id=$product_id' onclick="window.open(this.href, 'popup_win',
'left=100,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" id = 'linker' >See more</a>";
```

On your popup.php file (the popup page) you will get the product_id with the PHP $_GET method:

```
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
```

and then do whatever MySQL query you want, now that you know $product_id.

I hope this helps, if that's not exactly what you meant please add more details so I can revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess one of the most difficult parts of finding a solution is understanding the question in itself so, I'm probably asking the wrong questions but your solution has given me some clues and I will put it up once I can get it together.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Please post your solution and mark the correct answer once you figure it out.

Comment: I choose to go with your solution in the end because it might take me a while to solve mine and time I don't have. Thanks for the clue up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could first load all this records first and place them into the popup content or, make an ajax request, open the popup, and when the request is done successfully place the values returned into the popup content. Better with JQuery

Comment: Thanks for your response. The question I asked was a bit ambiguous. The main contents are displayed as thumbnails from the database leaving the user the choice to view more details of any one of them. The pop up is activated based on the user's choice. I'm trying a few things based on Yani's suggestion because all I really need is to get the product_id from the main page into the pop up.

Comment: Ok. well, with HTML5 you can insert custom attributes in your html tags. I don't know if I'm really understanding your question but, Insert the product_id within the tag like `<a href="#" data-product_id="<?php echo $product_id?>"><img src="path/to/img"></a>` then just get the product id with jquery using the .data() method and finally send an ajax request with the product_id. When you get the response, open the popup with all the produc info and display what you want.